# Inspect IOS Safari via Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to inspect a page in IOS Safari using Chrome Developer Tools??

I'm looking for a solution like Safari Desktop > iOS Safari.
I'm working in a windows machine and I don't have Safari.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I know of that would get close to that is [WeInRe](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/), but that's not the full Chrome Developer Tools.